# How to efficiently get a `string_view` for a substring of `std::string`

Tags: c++, view, c++17, stdstring

Using http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view as a reference, I see no way to do this more elegantly:

```
std::string s = "hello world!";
std::string_view v = s;
v = v.substr(6, 5); // "world"
```

Worse, the naive approach is a pitfall and leaves `v` a dangling reference to a temporary:

```
std::string s = "hello world!";
std::string_view v(s.substr(6, 5)); // OOPS!
```

I *seem to remember* something like there might be an addition to the standard library to return a substring as a view:

```
auto v(s.substr_view(6, 5));
```

I can think of the following workarounds:

```
std::string_view(s).substr(6, 5);
std::string_view(s.data()+6, 5);
// or even "worse":
std::string_view(s).remove_prefix(6).remove_suffix(1);
```

Frankly, I don't think any of these are very nice. Right now the best thing I can think of is using aliases to simply make things less verbose.

```
using sv = std::string_view;
sv(s).substr(6, 5);
```

Comment: "I don't think any of these are very nice" What is wrong with the first one? Seems completely clear to me. Edit: BTW combining two methods that have clear meaning individually (`string_view(s).substr(...)`) seems nicer than a single function doing two things at once (`.substr_view(...)`) even if it did exist.

Comment: @sehe: are you suggesting that `std::string::substr` should return a `std::string_view`?

Comment: @geza I strongly seem to remember additions to `std::basic_string<>` interface that would add an operation like `subtr_view`, indeed. I mentioned that in the question. I was hoping someone would respond and say "That's proposal Nxxxx which got rejected/accepted into C++zz or TSn"

Comment: @ArthurTacca since the operation is so common, I think there should be a 1 step operation, possibly also more efficient. And certainly less error-prone: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd180519dc9b2f00 A free function is now the best we can do (in absense of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Function_Call_Syntax)

Comment: @sehe It comes down to a matter of opinion. In my opinion, the function you're referring to is essentially "make a string view from a string and make a substring from it", and I consider it cleaner to expose these two operations separately and let them be composed, so long as it is not significantly longer than calling a free function (which it isn't).

Comment: @sehe The complaint you linked to wouldn't be fixed by adding a free function anyway. Instead you would need to *remove* the implicit constructor of `std::string_view` from `std::string` (but this would make it much more annoying to use in function calls). The real problem there is that returning a `string_view` is always dangerous and probably never advisable; it is exactly like returning a raw pointer, where you need to be sure you understand the lifetime of the pointed-to data.

Comment: @ArthurTacca Of course. See [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032307/how-to-efficiently-get-a-string-view-for-a-substring-of-stdstring?noredirect=1#comment79028403_46032307) again. It's a preference. And I value my style. And I know why I value it (reduce errors, because the combined operation would be more expressive _and_ tdo the right thing). Re. "The real problem": [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032307/how-to-efficiently-get-a-string-view-for-a-substring-of-stdstring?noredirect=1#comment79025792_46032475)

Comment: @sehe so the upshot of my alarmist ranting in the cpporg group is that no-one else seems to think that string_view is a problem. The answer seems to be, "just never return a string_view", adding string_view to the arbitrary list of classes that one should "just know" not to return. In which case the `std::string_view::substr()` method breaks its own rules, since it returns a string_view. So I guess the advice would be never to do this. Use a `std::string`.

Comment: @RichardHodges I think a better rule is "never return a `string_view` from a function that doesn't take a `string_view` as a parameter." Such functions are useful and safe IMO.

Comment: @JonathanSharman That rule needs to be a whole lot more accurate for it to work. But yeah, we need rules like that, and that's sad

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There's the free-function route, but unless you also provide overloads for `std::string` it's a snake-pit.

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

std::string_view sub_string(
  std::string_view s, 
  std::size_t p, 
  std::size_t n = std::string_view::npos)
{
  return s.substr(p, n);
}

int main()
{
  using namespace std::literals;

  auto source = "foobar"s;

  // this is fine and elegant...
  auto bar = sub_string(source, 3);

  // but uh-oh...
  bar = sub_string("foobar"s, 3);
}
```

IMHO the whole design of string_view is a horror show which will take us back to a world of segfaults and angry customers.

#### update:

Even adding overloads for `std::string` is a horror show. See if you can spot the subtle segfault timebomb...

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

std::string_view sub_string(std::string_view s, 
  std::size_t p, 
  std::size_t n = std::string_view::npos)
{
  return s.substr(p, n);
}

std::string sub_string(std::string&& s, 
  std::size_t p, 
  std::size_t n = std::string::npos)
{
  return s.substr(p, n);
}

std::string sub_string(std::string const& s, 
  std::size_t p, 
  std::size_t n = std::string::npos)
{
  return s.substr(p, n);
}

int main()
{
  using namespace std::literals;

  auto source = "foobar"s;
  auto bar = sub_string(std::string_view(source), 3);

  // but uh-oh...
  bar = sub_string("foobar"s, 3);
}
```

The compiler found nothing to warn about here. I am certain that a code review would not either.

I've said it before and I'll say it again, in case anyone on the c++ committee is watching, **allowing implicit conversions from `std::string` to `std::string_view` is a terrible error which will only serve to bring c++ into disrepute**.

#### Update

Having raised this (to me) rather alarming property of string_view on the cpporg message board, my concerns have been met with indifference.

The consensus of advice from this group is that `std::string_view` must never be returned from a function, which means that my first offering above is bad form.

There is of course no compiler help to catch times when this happens by accident (for example through template expansion).

As a result, `std::string_view` should be used with the utmost care, because from a memory management point of view it is equivalent to a copyable pointer pointing into the state of another object, which may no longer exist. However, it looks and behaves in all other respects like a value type.

Thus code like this:

```
auto s = get_something().get_suffix();
```

Is safe when `get_suffix()` returns a `std::string` (either by value or reference)

but is UB if get_suffix() is ever refactored to return a `std::string_view`.

Which in my humble view means that any user code that stores returned strings using `auto` will break if the libraries they are calling are ever refactored to return `std::string_view` in place of `std::string const&`.

So from now on, at least for me, "almost always auto" will have to become, "almost always auto, except when it's strings".

Comment: Smart thinking with the implicit conversion of the argument to `string_view`. How about: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e353f2a8f584998

Comment: @sehe updated with an even worse scenario - the result of good intentions going wrong. Expect to see this in a code base near you soon...

Comment: Agreed the second example is subtle, but luckily it has _nothing_ to do with the free function `sub_string`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7adf7a3cc661b173

Comment: @sehe I find it astonishing that the committee did not see this coming. It seems for once they have valued the quick-fix performance improvement of existing algorithms over code-safety. I fear this is a grave error.

Comment: Who says they didn't see it coming? It must have been weighing options. I mean, `string foo(); bool bar(string_view); auto check = bar(foo());` is safe and reasonable to want to allow.

Comment: @sehe: What Richard Hodges shows is precisely the reason why implicit conversion to ``const char *`` was disallowed. The committee's reasoning is not consistent, and I fully agree with RH, is likely to cause many developers (especially newcomers) untold pain.

Comment: @sehe of course I understand the rationale. It's attractive. It could be achieved safely if string_view were non-copyable and non-moveable. Then you couldn't return one from a function and all would be well.

Comment: To recap: yeah the free function is probably the most elegant, if you account for the pitfalls. (The design issues with http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_basic_string_view not being suitably ref-qualified and/or `explicit` is a bit off topic, but thanks for the insights none-the-less!)

Comment: @RichardHodges: can you please explain where the time bomb is here?

Comment: @geza your question validates my concern very nicely. The second assignment to `bar` is a `string_view` constructed from a `string_view` constructed from a temporary `std::string`, which has now been destructed.

Comment: @RichardHodges No. It's a string_view constructed from a from a temporary string, directly. Which is why I posted my de-mystifying version: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7adf7a3cc661b173 (`sub_string("foobar"s, 3)` returns another temporary `std::string`, correctly!). See how it's not related to your `::sub_string` at all :)

Comment: @RichardHodges: thanks for the answer! But I still fail to see it. Where is std::string_view involved here? Maybe I fail to see something very obvious here. Where do I think wrong? `source` and `bar` is `std::string`. At the second `bar` assignment, a temp `std::string` constructed, and the second `sub_string` is called, which returns a `std::string`. No `std::string_view` here...

Comment: @geza hah - you're right. I've fixed the bug inadvertently.

Comment: `sub_string("foobar"s, 3)` how can you expect anything other than trouble by constructing a view into a temporary object?

Comment: @einpoklum with std::string this is perfectly reasonable, it returns a new string.

Comment: I think we could remove a whole bunch of these comments, if you put in a section at the end (using "spoiler" markup) which explained the problem.

Comment: @RichardHodges: Well, a string view is not a string. So, are you saying it's the name that throws you off? Would you be ok if the function were called "sub_string_view"?

Comment: @einpoklum The problem isn't that hard to understand, but first it would have to _be understood_ by basically all programmers __and__ it would have to be constantly in their minds. That, I don't think is very safe. It would be akin to teaching pointers all over again.

Comment: @MartinBonner I'd be happy if all the non-related design rant bits go. My first comment here shows a single line [`=delete` declaration that handles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e353f2a8f584998) that tangential issue.

Comment: @RichardHodges, .... Great catch!.. Time for one additional entry in the CppCoreGuidlines :-). And time to once again, make the compiler treat some `std::` types specially. haha... Maybe we should add a new GCC `W` flag, ditto Clang: `-Wtemporary-basic_string-to-basic_string_view` ...:-)

Comment: @WhiZTiM how about this in the core guidelines, "thou shalt not create objects that pretend to be values in a pointless quest for nice-looking code. Pointers are pointers, values are values."

Comment: @RichardHodges come on. The name is `string_view`. ***View***.

Comment: @sehe before c++11 I would have agreed with you. But now its name is `auto`. **auto**. See? no clues at all by looking at user code as to whether it's a safe value-object or a dangerous reference object.

Comment: Well. Down that road lies madness. `auto` is a tool, not a requirement. Besides it's really off topic. The same argument goes for any 'proper' non-value type. Meanwhile the name of `string_view` is really not `auto` by any stretch of imagination.

Comment: What does character *s* do at the end of this expression auto source = "foobar"s ?

Comment: @bigdata2 it constructs a std::string - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s

Comment: `// this is fine and elegant... auto bar = sub_string(source, 3);`

This is NOT fine. You're returning a pointer to a temporary that you created in sub_string(): `return s.substr(p, n);`. That is going to explode 100%.

Answer (score 61):

You can use the conversion operator from **std::string** to **std::string_view**:

```
std::string s = "hello world!";
std::string_view v = std::string_view(s).substr(6, 5);
```

Comment: This approach is not obviously efficient (i.e. does it do the job without allocating an extra temporary buffers?), so a comment supporting the claim to efficiency would be good.  In fact, it looks like this approach is very contra-indicated because `v` points at a temporary buffer that immediately becomes invalid.

Comment: @JohnDoggett: What are you talking about? Why should there be a temporary buffer?

Comment: Imho this is a far better solution than the accepted one.

Comment: `.substr(6, 5)` allocates a new `std::string` but it is a temporary and goes away at the `;`, leaving the `v` pointing at a buffer that has been cleared.

Comment: @caps no, [`string_view::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/substr) returns a view  based on the original view.  Perhaps it would have been less confusing if they'd called it `subview`?

Comment: @M.M you are correct. I thought the code sample was calling `string::substr`.

Comment: I think this is the best practice. I think if you would like to explain in your answer that your solution need no extra allocation and copy, your answer will get much more attention and benefit more people. 

Comment: not only is it not worse than calling `string::substr` in many cases it's _more_ efficient.

Answer (score 5):

This is how you can efficiently create a sub-string string_view.

```
#include <string>
inline std::string_view substr_view(const std::string& source, size_t offset = 0,
                std::string_view::size_type count = 
                std::numeric_limits<std::string_view::size_type>::max()) {
    if (offset < source.size()) 
        return std::string_view(source.data() + offset, 
                        std::min(source.size() - offset, count));
    return {};
}

#include <iostream>
int main(void) {
  std::cout << substr_view("abcd",3,11) << "\n";

  std::string s {"0123456789"};
  std::cout << substr_view(s,3,2) << "\n";

  // be cautious about lifetime, as illustrated at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view
  std::string_view bad = substr_view("0123456789"s, 3, 2); // "bad" holds a dangling pointer
  std::cout << bad << "\n"; // possible access violation

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to highlight a "bad use", as the given example could easily evolve into one.  Proposed an edit to do just that.

Comment: Prevent the bad case from happening -> std::string_view substr_view(std::string const&&, etc.) = delete;

Comment: This one should have been marked the correct answer, its the only correct answer on this page. You cannot create a string_view from `substr` unless you want to keep that substr in memory for the lifetime of your string_view. The accepted answer below is completely incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that the question is about C++17, but it's worth noting that C++20 introduced a `string_view` constructor that accepts two iterators to char (or whatever the base type is) which allows writing

```
std::string_view v{ s.begin() +6, s.begin()+6 +5 };
```

Not sure if there is a cleaner syntax, but it's not difficult to

```
#define RANGE(_container,_start,_length) (_container).begin() + (_start), (_container).begin() + (_start) + (_length)
```

for a final

```
std::string_view v{ RANGE(s,6,5) };
```

PS:  I called `RANGE`'s first parameter `_container` instead of `_string` for a reason:  the macro can be used with any Container (or class supporting at least `begin()` and `end()`), even as part of a function call like

```
auto pisPosition= std::find( RANGE(myDoubleVector,11,23), std::numbers::pi );
```

PPS:  When possible, prefer C++20's *actual* ranges library to this poor person's solution.

Comment: However, beware that unlike the `substr` functions, this has no range validation at all.